# The purpose of YUI subscribe?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, yui

What is the purpose of subscribe? Here is my calendar control:

Code:

```
var myCal = new yuiCalendar('myCal');
var ripDate = function (type, args) {
   // My code
}

myCal.selectEvent.subscribe(ripDate);
```

Is this a custom event? Am I overriding the default event? Does this event get fired in the background irrespective if I subscribe to it? In .NET the control events are fired irrespective if you use them or not. How does this differ as to using `.on(...)`?

Can someone please give a decent description of using subscribe, if there is any documentation (with possible sample code) then it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YUI has a lot of documentation and examples.

You are not overriding the event by subscribing to it, you are listening for it, and acting upon any occurrences.  You can subscribe as many times as you like, and they will be listened for in the order subscribed.

[Subscribing to a CustomEvent docs](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/event/#customsubscribe)

.on is an alias for AddListener, which is used to listen for DOM events.

Start with [YUI 2's homepage](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/2/) and click around for docs and samples.

Comment: Yes I have been through alot of the documentation. I'm not a seasoned JavaScript developer, so I don't know what suscribing means. And no where do I find what it means and why you want to do it. This is what I wanted to know.

Comment: By subscribing you are waiting to run your code when something happens.  In your case, the "selectEvent" of the YUI Calendar control.  http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/calendar/#events